# Why are 'electric', 'electricity' and 'electrician' pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology

Why is the ⟨c⟩ in *electric*, *electricity* and *electrician* pronounced differently?

- Electric → /ɪˈlɛktrɪ**k**/
- Electricity → /ˌɛl.ɪkˈtrɪ**s**.ə.ti/
- Electrician → /ˌɪl.ɛkˈtrɪ**ʃ**.ən/

My main question is: why is the second **⟨c⟩** in all these words pronounced differently even though they're derived from the same root?

> **Origin:** Mid 17th century: from modern Latin **[electricus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/electricus#Latin)**, from Latin **electrum** ‘amber’, from Greek **ēlektron**.

The root word had a [k] sound which is the same in the word *electric* but when it's suffixed, the [k] changes to [s] (in *electri**c**ity*). As for *electrician*, I assume it was pronounced with /sj/ which coalesced into /ʃ/ due to *yod-coalescence* (assimilation), it's clear. But why is the last **c** in *electricity* not pronounced as [k]?

Other examples are *eccentric - eccentricity*, *authentic - authenticity* etc.

Consider *panic*:

- Panic → /ˈpæn.ɪ**k**/

When *panic* is suffixed, we add the letter **⟨k⟩** in order to keep the same pronunciation as the root word because if we don't add the orthographic **⟨k⟩**, the pronunciation will change (i.e. [k] will change to [s]).

- Panic → panic**k**y /ˈpæn.ɪ.**k**i/

So why don't we add a **k** to *electricity*, *authenticity* and *eccentricity*? Or why do why add **⟨k⟩** to *panicky*?

---

<sub>NOTE: Most of the transcriptions are from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)</sub>

Comment: Because English is eccentric and exhibits eccentricity...?

Comment: The main reason the OP is puzzled is because they started from the wrong assumption and ran into a contradiction. The wrong assumption is of course what's taught in schools and must be correct, except it isn't -- that English spelling represents English pronunciation.  That's just wrong. English spelling is what you sweep out of the grate at the bottom of the furnace after several centuries of clinkers. Every century  since English printing started in 1476 has had its own fads and fashions of spelling, and some stuck. That's it. Not accurate at all. Just arbitrary.

Comment: To the close-voters: Do you really think this question "can be answered using commonly-available references"? I searched through heaps of different websites and linguistics books before asking the question but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the difference is the phenomenon of [Palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)). In late Latin, the /k/ sound (written 'c') gradually changed if there was a front vowel (such as /i/ or /e/) following. If you listen carefully while you say the words 'cut' and 'kit', you will find that the /k/ sound is different in the two cases, because the back of your tongue is already raised for the /ɪ/ in 'kit'. Over time this difference became greater until the sound became /t͡ʃ/, (the sound in English "Church"). This sound remained in Italian, but moved further to become /s/ in French. English took a lot of its words and its spelling from French, so this is why in English, 'c' usually has a /s/ sound before 'i', 'y', and 'e', and usually a /k/ sound otherwise.   This is why "electricity" has a /s/ sound rather than a /k/.

Later, within English, when that /sɪ/ sound was followed by another vowel, it tended to become /ʃ/ (the sound at the beginning of "ship"). This is why "mission" and "official" both have /ʃ/ rather than /sɪ/ in them. This is why "electrician" has a /ʃ/ sound.

Note that I've described this in terms of writing, but actually these processes happen even without writing. Romans in the street would pronounce 'locus' with a /k/ and 'loci' with a /s/, even if they couldn't read: they just knew that that was the pattern of the words, the same way that we know that that *heard* ends with a /d/ but *looked* ends with a /t/, whether we can read or not.

For the final point: the set of endings *-ic*, *-icity*, *-ician* are well established and in some cases were taken from French as a group. (French has *-icité*, rather than *-icity*, but that's a detail). Even though *electric* and its family were coined after the period when English was taking these sets from French, the pattern existed, and people simply applied to the new word.

*Panicky* is different, though, because it's coined in English, with the English suffix *-y*. Suppose you wanted to apply this same suffix to *electric*: You would say *electric-y* with the /k/ sound, and if you needed to write it, you would write *electricky*.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a linguistic process known as *velar softening*. It softens the velar -- /k/ in "electric" -- when it precedes a front vowel (/I/ in "electricity").

Read [this paper by Morris Halle on Velar Softening](http://web.mit.edu/morrishalle/pubworks/papers/2005_Halle_Palatalization_or_Velar_Softening.pdf) and [this one by Prof. Yehuda N. Falk](http://pluto.huji.ac.il/%7Emsyfalk/WordStructure/Palatalization.pdf) for details.

Hope that helps!

(Sorry, no IPA atm.)

Comment: It would be better to include the relevant parts of the papers you link, those links may go dead which would hurt the answer in the long term.